# Applying patches that time out on composer update?

Tags: composer

I've just updated to MacOS ventura 13.0.1. How do I get composer update to work?

- Applying patches for pear/mail_mime
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/74e25f27bb3be32519657539afe8a285c6c99a08/tools/scripts/composer/patches/mail_mime_crm_3133.patch (Apply patch for CRM-3133 wordwrap body to be 750 characters to apply with RFC 2821)
  Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: The process "patch '-p1' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d '/Sites/electrifyingbradfield/vendor/pear/mail_mime' < '/var/folders/q4/6fm4gd05575d6snq43_pcggm0000gn/T/63830c0849b7b.patch'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

The version of patch

```
 patch -v
 patch 2.0-12u11-Apple
```

The patch file is there

```
cat /var/folders/q4/6fm4gd05575d6snq43_pcggm0000gn/T/63830c0849b7b.patch 
--- Mail/mime.php   2020-06-27 18:35:27.000000000 +1000
+++ Mail/mime.php   2020-07-25 08:36:14.570334621 +1000
@@ -1527,6 +1527,9 @@
             $this->{$type} .= $data;
         }
 
+        // wordwrap the txtbody to be 750 characters to comply with RFC 2821
+        // CRM-3133
+        $this->{$type} = wordwrap($this->{$type}, 750);
         return true;
     }
```

If I run the command manually there is a prompt for 'file to patch'

```
% patch -p1 --no-backup-if-mismatch -d  /Users/jrobens/Sites/electrifyingbradfield/vendor/pear/mail_mime < '/var/folders/q4/6fm4gd05575d6snq43_pcggm0000gn/T/63830c0849b7b.patch'

File to patch: ^C%
```

The man page provides 2 scenarios

> ```
>  patch [-bCcEeflNnRstuv] [-B backup-prefix] [-D symbol] [-d directory] [-g vcs-option] [-F max-fuzz] [-i patchfile] [-o out-file] [-p strip-count]
>      [-r rej-name] [-T | -Z] [-V t | nil | never | none] [-x number] [-Y prefix] [-> z backup-ext] [--quoting-style style] [--posix] [origfile [patchfile]]
> ```
>
> patch <patchfile

This works

> patch  -d vendor/pear/mail_mime < '/var/folders/q4/6fm4gd05575d6snq43_pcggm0000gn/T/63830c0849b7b.patch'

> patching file 'Mail/mime.php'

Adding -p1 does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing gpatch is the solution recommended here. The symptoms are the same, the process freezes waiting for input on 'which file to patch'.

https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/issues/423